# Binding Syncfusion Scheduler c#

Tags: c#, ios, scheduler, syncfusion, sfschedule

I would appreciate any help on creating a simple Syncfusion `SfSchedule` appointment collection and binding it to the scheduler (`SFSchedulerDataSource`?).

I am using Xamarin.iOS and C#. I can only find documentation in objective-c, Swift and others, not in C#, and the commands are not the same, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data binding for Schedule can be done through it's `Appointments` property, respective documentation for C# is available in the below link,

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ios/sfschedule/data-bindings